# How do I configure the u-boot video driver for a 320x240 LVDS display on an iMX6 board?

Tags: embedded, hardware, u-boot, imx6

I have a custom hardware device that uses a Variscite i.MX6Q (quad-core) to drive a 320x240 display. Once the linux kernel starts booting, the LCD display works great - no issues at all. However, prior to that the boot loader (u-boot)  shows a white screen (sometimes with faint vertical lines) for about 0.25s, then goes black for about 8s until the kernel takes over (reinitializing the display and correctly showing the kernel's own splash screen).

[image]

Since the linux kernel can drive the display just fine, I'm sure I've just mis-configured something in my u-boot setup...but I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out what and where! Resources / things I've tried include:

- **[Porting LVDS LCD With Low Resolution to i.MX6](https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-172312)** - This seems highly relevant, but refers to tweaking linux kernel drivers instead of uboot and I'm not experienced enough to port the knowledge to uboot.
- **[U-Boot splash screen - LVDS](https://www.toradex.com/community/questions/18124/u-boot-splash-screen-lvds.html)** - This seems soooo close to the problem I'm having, but doesn't list a clear solution. One response in the forum linked to a suggestion to invert the polarity of one of the clocks, which I tried but did not notice any difference.
- **[How to display splash screen on parallel LCD in u-boot](https://community.nxp.com/thread/305293#320514)** - In the same theme as the prior posts, this again hints at an issue with specifying clocks for low-res displays.
- **[i.mx6 33.26MHz LVDS panel cannot display in u-boot](https://community.nxp.com/thread/464092)** - Following these instructions, I modified ...../uboot/drivers/video/ipu_common.c and set the g_ldb_clk struct .rate members to 6400000, but that seemed to have no effect.
- **[Adding Displays to iMX Developer's Kits](https://www.embeddedartists.com/sites/default/files/docs/misc/iMX_Adding_Displays.pdf)** *[Warning - PDF!]* - Instructions on how to add support for new displays to iMX boards; section 6.1.4 talks about iMX6Q. However, I've added the proper display timings to the displays[] var (see code below) and I'm still having problems.

From my custom board schematics, I know that I need to configure a PWM backlight display on PWM2 and backlight enable/disable on GPIO 5-13, and I need to provide custom display timings. So, the relevant sections in ..../uboot/board/variscite/mx6var_som.c:

```
struct display_info_t const displays[] = {{
    .bus    = -1,
    .addr   = 0,
    .pixfmt = IPU_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
    .detect = detect_MyCustomBoard,
    .enable = lvds_enable_disable,
    .mode   = {
        .name           = "VAR-QVGA MX6CB-R",
        .refresh        = 60,  /* optional */
        .xres           = 320,
        .yres           = 240,
        .pixclock       = MHZ2PS(6.4),
        .left_margin    = 64,
        .right_margin   = 20,
        .upper_margin   = 8,
        .lower_margin   = 4,
        .hsync_len      = 4,
        .vsync_len      = 10,
        .sync           = FB_SYNC_EXT,
        .vmode          = FB_VMODE_NONINTERLACED
    } },
    ...
};

static void setup_display(void)
{
    ...
    /* Turn off backlight until display is ready */
    SETUP_IOMUX_PAD(PAD_DISP0_DAT19__GPIO5_IO13 | MUX_PAD_CTRL(NO_PAD_CTRL));
    gpio_direction_output(IMX_GPIO_NR(5, 13), 0);

    /* Setup the backlight dimmer (via PWM) */
    SETUP_IOMUX_PAD(PAD_DISP0_DAT9__PWM2_OUT | MUX_PAD_CTRL(BACKLIGHT_PWM_CTRL));
    pwm_init(VAR_SOM_BACKLIGHT_PWM_ID, VAR_SOM_BACKLIGHT_PERIOD, 0);
    pwm_config(VAR_SOM_BACKLIGHT_PWM_ID, 0, VAR_SOM_BACKLIGHT_PERIOD);

    ...

    /* Turn on LDB0, LDB1, IPU,IPU DI0 clocks */
    reg = readl(&mxc_ccm->CCGR3);
    reg |=  MXC_CCM_CCGR3_LDB_DI0_MASK | MXC_CCM_CCGR3_LDB_DI1_MASK;
    writel(reg, &mxc_ccm->CCGR3);

    /* set LDB0, LDB1 clk select to 011/011 */
    reg = readl(&mxc_ccm->cs2cdr);
    reg &= ~(MXC_CCM_CS2CDR_LDB_DI0_CLK_SEL_MASK
         | MXC_CCM_CS2CDR_LDB_DI1_CLK_SEL_MASK);
    reg |= (1 << MXC_CCM_CS2CDR_LDB_DI0_CLK_SEL_OFFSET)
          | (1 << MXC_CCM_CS2CDR_LDB_DI1_CLK_SEL_OFFSET);
    writel(reg, &mxc_ccm->cs2cdr);
    ...
}

int splash_screen_prepare(void)
{
    ...

    /* Turn on backlight */
    gpio_set_value(IMX_GPIO_NR(5, 13), 1);
    pwm_config(VAR_SOM_BACKLIGHT_PWM_ID, VAR_SOM_BACKLIGHT_PERIOD*127/256, VAR_SOM_BACKLIGHT_PERIOD);
    ...
}
```

For comparison, here are the relevant sections of my linux device tree:

```
&pwm2 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_pwm2_1>;
    status = "okay";
};

backlight {
    compatible = "pwm-backlight";
    pwms = <&pwm2 0 50000>;
    brightness-levels = <0 4 8 16 32 64 128 248>;
    default-brightness-level = <7>;
    status = "okay";
};

&ldb {
    status = "okay";

    lvds-channel@0 {
        fsl,data-mapping = "spwg";
        fsl,data-width = <24>;
        status = "okay";
        primary;

        display-timings {
            native-mode = <&timing0r>;
            timing0r: hsd100pxn1 {
                clock-frequency = <6400000>;
                hactive = <320>;
                vactive = <240>;
                hback-porch = <64>;
                hfront-porch = <20>;
                vback-porch = <8>;
                vfront-porch = <4>;
                hsync-len = <4>;
                vsync-len = <10>;
            };
        };
    };

    ...
};

&iomuxc {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_hog>;

    imx6qdl-var-som-mx6 {

        pinctrl_hog: hoggrp {
            fsl,pins = <

                ...
                /* LCD Enable on GPIO 5-13 */
                MX6QDL_PAD_DISP0_DAT19__GPIO5_IO13  0xc0000000

                ...
            >;
        };
```

In terms of hardware, the LVDS signal from the iMX6 is converted to parallel RGB by a TI SN65LVDS822 FlatlinkTM LVDS receiver, which drives a 320x240 QVGA Okaya RH320240T-3x5AP-A display.

The framework I'm using is Yocto (Krogoth release), which includes:

- U-Boot 2015.04-mx6+g535519b: git://github.com/varigit/uboot-imx.git, branch imx_v2015.04_4.1.15_1.1.0_ga_var03, commit 535519
- Linux kernel 4.1.15: git://github.com/varigit/linux-2.6-imx.git, branch imx-rel_imx_4.1.15_2.0.0_ga-var01, commit 5a4b34

I do have a Variscite DevKit, and when I boot the SOM in the DevKit (with an appropriate device tree and associated drivers) everything works great and I see both the uboot splash image as well as the linux kernel splash image. This implies that the image I'm using for the uboot splash is valid, can be read by uboot, etc.

There is one other kicker: I do not have serial console access on my production board set :(.

So, the big question here is what am I doing wrong in my uboot display driver initialization? At this point, I'd even welcome strategies on how to go about debugging this (although I don't have access to an oscilloscope).

Comment: It looks as though the fact that the backlight is turned off during the u-boot process is sufficient to explain what you see. Do you have access to the U-boot source? I would be looking for code which relates to the GPIO which is used for the backlight (as per your kernel code) and/or the pad MUX setup.

Comment: @CrackajackDev did you get any solution?

Comment: I did enable the backlight in u-boot (per @DavidHoadley's recommendation). Now when the device boots, the boot loader shows a garbled screen that quickly (over 1s or so?) fades to all white. I also opened a ticket with Variscite, but they said we'd need to engage paid board support resources for them to investigate. Long story short, the customer decided not to pursue the issue further, so we've left things as-is.